# Search through list of strings and determine if there is an exact match in separate list of strings. python. sentiment analysis

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a list of keywords and a list of sentences:

```
keywords = ['foo', 'bar', 'joe', 'mauer']
listOfStrings = ['I am frustrated', 'this task is foobar', 'mauer is awesome']
```

How can I loop through my listOfStrings and determine if they contain any of the keywords...Must be an exact match!  Such that:

```
>>for i in listOfStrings:
    for p in keywords:
       if p in i:
         print i

>> 'mauer is awesome'
```

(because 'foobar' is NOT an exact match with 'foo' or 'bar', function should only catch 'foobar' if it is a keyword)

I suspect re.search may be the way, but I cant figure out how to loop through list, using variables rather than verbatim expressions using the re module.
Thanks

Comment: what is wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: @Ryan Saxe: It's pseudocode. It expresses what he wants, not how to code what he wants.

Comment: @RyanSaxe The posted code also prints `"this task is foobar"` but shouldn’t.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying andrewdotn, patashu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking if each keyword is contained anywhere in the string, you can break the sentences down into words, and check whether each of them is a keyword. Then you won’t have problems with partial matches.

Here, `RE_WORD` is defined as the regular expression of a word-boundary, at least one character, and then another word boundary. You can use [`re.findall()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) to find all words in the string. `re.compile()` pre-compiles the regular expression so that it doesn’t have to be parsed from scratch for every line.

`frozenset()` is an [efficient data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28abstract_data_type%29#Implementations_2) that can answer the question “is the given word in the frozen set?” faster than is possible by scanning through a long list of keywords and trying every one of them.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import re

RE_WORD = re.compile(r'\b[a-zA-Z]+\b')

keywords = frozenset(['foo', 'bar', 'joe', 'mauer'])
listOfStrings = ['I am frustrated', 'this task is foobar', 'mauer is awesome']

for i in listOfStrings:
    for word in RE_WORD.findall(i):
        if word in keywords:
            print i
            continue
```

Comment: Thanks @andrewdotn, I am a bit confused by re.compile parameter, but this appears to work very well.

Answer (score 1):

A much better idea for exact matches is to store the keywords in a set

```
keywords = {'foo', 'bar', 'joe', 'mauer'}
listOfStrings = ['I am frustrated', 'this task is foobar', 'mauer is awesome']

[s for s in listOfStrings if any(w in keywords for w in s.split())]
```

This only tests each word in `listOfStrings` once. Your method (or using regex) looks at every word in `listOfStrings` for *each keyword*. As the number of keywords grows, that will be very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you surround a word with the regex metacharacter `\b` then use it as a regex, it is required to match on word boundaries:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

> The metacharacter \b is an anchor like the caret and the dollar sign. It matches at a position that is called a "word boundary". This match is zero-length.

In addition, make sure that your python regex uses `re.IGNORECASE`: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE

And don't forget that `\` may be considered a metacharacter both in the language's string parser AND for the regex engine itself, meaning it will have to be doubled up into `\\b`.